# Find out check in and out time of emp, who check in and out within a minute

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables like:

Table 1: CheckInOut

```
CID | EmpId | PunchTime | CodeInOut
=================================
10 | 101 | 11:30:45 | Green
11 | 102 | 11:30:55 | Brown
12 | 103 | 11:31:20 | Green
13 | 101 | 11:31:44 | Red
14 | 103 | 11:32:05 | Orange
15 | 104 | 11:35:00 | Yellow
16 | 103 | 11:36:02 | Green
17 | 101 | 11:36:20 | Orange
18 | 104 | 11:37:00 | Red
19 | 103 | 11:37:01 | Red
20 | 103 | 11:40:01 | Black
```

Table 2: Emp

```
EmpId | FName | LName | ContactNo
101 | Jack | Read | 456789
102 | Mike | jobs | 556789
103 | Stev | more | 656789
104 | Andy | Jara | 756789
```

I want to find out only the list of employees who checked In and out within a minute.

The result should be something like this:

```
EmpId | FName | LName | CID | CodeInOut | ContactNo
101 | Jack | Read | 10,13 | Green,Red | 456789
103 | Stev | more | 12,14,16,19 | Green,Orange,Green,Red |656789
```

Help will be really appreciated.

Comment: mysql or oracle? Please tag only the relevant database.

Comment: How can we tell a checkin from a checkout in the `checkinout` table? There is no obvious distinction.

Comment: Based on PunchTime, I think we need to loop with the same EmpId.

Comment: @Avengers . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need string aggregation and date/time functions to solve this.  So let me assume that your database is Oracle (its syntax in this regard is closer to the standard).

You want to aggregate the rows in `checkinout`, but only when they are close enough to neighboring rows.  Use `lag()` and `lead()` and then filtering:

```
select empid,
       listagg(cid, ',') within group (order by cid) as cids,
       listagg(CodeInOut, ',') within group (order by cid) as CodeInOuts
from (select cio.*,
             lag(punchtime) over by (partition by empid order by punchtime) as prev_pt,
             lead(punchtime) over by (partition by empid order by punchtime) as next_pt
      from checkinout cio
     ) cio
where prev_pt > punchtime - interval '1' minute or
      next_pt < punchtime + interval '1' minute
group by empid;
```

You can bring in the remaining columns from `emp` and including the extra columns in the `select` and `group by`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=678a32cf252af20f9c0054547922aa12) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I am getting error- ORA-30484: missing window specification for this function
30484. 00000 -  "missing window specification for this function"
*Cause:    All window functions should be followed by window specification,
           like <function>(<argument list>) OVER (<window specification>)

Comment: @Avengers . . . I don't know what my fingers were thinking.  I fixed the syntax and added a db<>fiddle.